# How to wait until VirtualBox has finished loading to execute next command in Windows Batch?

Tags: shell, command-line, batch-file, virtualbox, wait

I've been having some trouble with a recent CMD batch file I wrote.  This is supposed to launch my development environment at work, and for the most part it works:

```
@echo off
start cmd.exe
start notepad++.exe
start sublime_text.exe
start outlook.exe
start communicator.exe
start "* Starting VirtualBox ..." virtualbox.exe
start sh.exe
start firefox.exe
```

The challenge I'm facing is that I want to start git-bash, (sh.exe) but in the corporate config virtualbox must be up and running for vagrant, a shell-based virtualbox manager to load properly.  So, because of this dependency, I need virtualbox.exe to launch and completely finish loading (we don't need to "start" and boxes) before then launching git-bash shell (sh.exe).

I've searched but fallen short on how to do this.  I keep getting results recommending:

- /wait
- pinging localhost (n) times to create a timer hack

The problem with these options is the /wait won't move to the next command until VirtualBox is closed -- that's not what I want.  The second option is a time-based wait which also does not solve my problem in this case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not ping the virtual host until it responds?

Comment: I guess because the VM may not have networking enabled, see my property solution for a more robust method :)

Answer (score 7):

Wow! Thanks **paulm** for inspiration.

Found one great opportunity!

I was browsing build-it guest OS properties with command :

```
 VBoxControl guestproperty enumerate -patterns *
```

and I've found a nice property "**/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/LoggedInUsers**"

During guest OS boot this property changes from "No value set!" through value "0" to "1" (if user logs in automatically).
Works fine on both Windows and linux.

```
>VBoxManage guestproperty get "WIN7_32" "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/LoggedInUsers"
No value set!

>VBoxManage guestproperty get "WIN7_32" "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/LoggedInUsers"
Value: 0

>VBoxManage guestproperty get "WIN7_32" "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/LoggedInUsers"
Value: 1
```

So you don't need to add anything to Start-up on your guest OS! Sweet!

Also you can even use **wait** :

```
VBoxManage guestproperty wait "WIN7_32" "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/LoggedInUsers"
```

but keep in mind, that this command will return 0 once guest OS reaches Welcome screen

Comment: Seems like "LoggedInUsers" is no longer available (5.2.22). `VBoxManage GuestProperty Enumerate <running host>` reveals an equally usable property: `NoLoggedInUsers`, which is a boolean, but since we are only waiting for it to become available, that does not matter here.

Comment: "LoggedInUsers" *is* available, but for some reason (bug?) you can't wait for it. You can 'get' it, though.

Answer (score 3):

The "best" way to do this is by using VBoxManage on the host machine combined with VBoxControl on the guest machine using properties.

The way this works is that the host machine will wait for a property to be set, and the guest machine will set this property when ever you consider the machine to have "loaded". For me I simply set the property from a logon script.

So on my Linux host I say:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty wait My_Virtual_Machine_Name Wait_For_Logon_Event
```

This will wait/block forever, you can add a timeout if you wish.

Then on the Windows Guest in a logon script or machine start script I execute:

```
VBoxControl guestproperty set Wait_For_Logon_Event Event_Now_Set
```

This then causes the execution to continue on the host side:

```
Name: Wait_For_Logon_Event, value: Event_Now_Set, flags:
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Unfortunately I have left that contract so I will be unable to test it. But, perhaps this info will be useful in the future. Best regards.

Comment: I think, that using properties instead of running programs in loop is much better approach. It took about 2 minutes to find the misprint in "guuestproperty set", but works fine now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you have observed, the VirtualBox/VBoxManage process will return and exit once the VM has actually turned on. There isn't a good way to hook into the guest at start, though one thing you can do is instruct VirtualBox to run a command and check for the exit code. I would insert this code in your batch file script right after starting the guest VM but before you want to start `sh.exe`:

```
:CheckVBox
VBoxManage guestcontrol Win8 exec --image c:\Windows\System32\ipconfig.exe --wait-exit --username Goyuix --password VirtualBoxRox
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 (
  REM Do something to sleep here, pinging localhost or timeout
  GOTO CheckVBox
)
REM VM Ready, go ahead and fire up other apps that depend on it
```

**Note:** you will need to have the path to the `VBoxManage` executable in your PATH environment variable. On Windows, it is typically: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox

Granted, you would probably want something more robust that just running `ipconfig` to detect if the VM is really ready. I am not sure what services etc. you would depend on having available, but this might be good enough to get you over the hump and can certainly be adapted to check for service status etc.

Comment: Thanks @Goyuix.  Where do I type this stuff in?  A config file of some sort?  Command line?

Comment: You are welcome! This is a great question. I have updated the original answer to make it more clear that you should add the code to your existing batch script. If this solves your problem I would appreciate the up-vote and accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`LoggedInUsers` does no longer seem to work with `wait` (VirtualBox 5.2.22), `get` does work, though. So I've switched to another property :

```
VBoxManage guestproperty wait <host> "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/NoLoggedInUsers"
```

Since we are only waiting for this property to come available, you could probably use any of the guestproperties under `/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS` which are not available for a non-running machine. You can find out which they are by

```
vboxmanage guestproperty enumerate <host> | grep GuestInfo/OS
```

where `<host>` should be a running. Then compare that list to the one for a non-running machine.